# RGB and SRGB difference and their use

Tags: led, pic, microchip, rgb

I am working on a project which include displaying RGB colors. I would like to know what is the difference between RGB and SRGB. Is it possible to have srgb colors in led. As SRGB has been used for printers, monitors and internet colors.

Answer (score 7):

sRGB is a colorspace. That is, it defines a reference system in which a perceived color can be expressed by three numbers: R, G and B.
If you want to reproduce a color expressed in sRGB value using three LEDs, you have several computations to perform:

- First, you have to know the spectrum of the three LED you are using. ( I hope: one green, one red and one blue)
- Second you have to build a model that allows you to match the sRGB defined color to a mixture of your three available spectra. If you have the tabulated spectra, you can do this mathematical, but usually, due to dispersion, it's done by measurements.
  The use of a colorimeter or a spectrometer is required here.

OR

You don't care to be colorimetrically correct and just match the R, G and B value to the LED power accordingly. You can also set a gain and an offset for every channel, and adjust manually the values until you get an acceptable result. And I you want better result, you can also set a gamma value in addition to your gain and offset.

Comment: Note that if it's required to have very good results: ultra low cost colorimeters meant for monitor calibration are available.

Comment: What do you mean by offset and gain for every channel

Comment: I mean that you match your led control using a linear law such as: Led_r = gain_r * R + offset_r. Same for G and B. If it's not enough, add an exponent term (Gamma value)